# ATEHNA (SQL) Need to convert a string that is in 9/29/2021 2:36:32 PM format into a Timestamp type in but keep getting error

Tags: sql, parsing, amazon-athena

I am trying to convert a timestamp string to timestamp with date_parse, but keep getting an error of : "INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Illegal pattern component: i"

String is formatted as such: 9/29/2021 2:36:32 PM

```
parse_datetime(end_timestamp_t,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s %p')
```

have also tried:

```
parse_datetime(end_timestamp_t,'%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s %p') as this,
```

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all it seems that you are using MySQL date format patterns while `parse_datetime` expects Java ones. You need to use `date_parse` for MySQl ones. Secondary in your date string example you have `/` as delimeter, not `-`, so you need to modify format string accrodingly:

```sql
select date_parse('9/29/2021 2:36:32 PM','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s %p')
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2021-09-29 02:36:32.000 |

Comment: Appreciate the help so much! - I am still receiving the error below...can you please adivse?

INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "10/19/2021 10:01:59 P" is malformed at "P"

Comment: @user2216856 it means that date you have provided is missing `M` from `PM`

Comment: I checked the source data and there is not M missing from that date, any other idea what is causing this error?

Comment: @user2216856 the one you have provided in error message does.